# ¿Como "chancar o machacar" una funcion con otra?

Tags: javascript

```
function lalo () {
    $('<ul id="lalo-uno"><li>UNO</li></ul>').appendTo('body');
}

function lalo2 (  ) {
    $('<ul id="lalo-dos"><li>DOS</li></ul>').appendTo('body');
}

window.onresize = function () {

    if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
        lalo2();
    } else {
        lalo();
    }
}
```

Hace 2 dias que no puedo resolver esto, ayuda por favor! Mi codigo de arriba funciona pero hay un problema. Cuando el ancho del navegador es mayor a 500 me muestra la funcion LALO2() y cuando es menor me muestra LALO(), el problema es que cuando me muestra una funcion no me quita la anterior, y eso es lo que yo quiero, que elimine la otra, como si fuera un efecto hover, que al entrar agrega un color y al salir se lo quita...lo mismo pero con las funciones.

Answer (score 0):

Para que quede bien tendríamos que conocer un poco mejor la estructura de la página. O por ejemplo si el `ul` que intentas añadir es realmente el último elemento o puede haber otros a posteri.

A modo de pista algo que puede funcionar es asignar un `id` a cada elemento del menú y remover los elementos cuando se produce el evento de resize.

```
function lalo () {
    $('<ul id="lalo-uno"><li>UNO</li></ul>').appendTo('body');
}

function lalo2 (  ) {
    $('<ul id="lalo-dos"><li>DOS</li></ul>').appendTo('body')
}


window.onresize = function () {
    $('#lalo-uno').remove();
    $('#lalo-dos').remove();
    if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
        lalo2();
    } else {
        lalo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hace 2 dias logre hacerlo con el remove...pero pense que se podia eliminar la funcion...porque suponiendo que tengo muchos elementos que remover, para evitar remover uno por uno,pense que simplemente podria inhabilitar la funcion...pero veo que no se puede

Comment: Como dicen en otra respuesta si es posible deberías encapsular todo lo que quieras eliminar en un `div` y eliminar ese `div`. También puedes echar un ojo a [replaceWith](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Comment: Creo que estás mezclando dos conceptos. Una cosa es deshabilitar una función y otra es deshacer los cambios del DOM que ha hecho una función (que creo que es lo que quieres y que no es posible hacerlo de una forma automática). De todas formas, creo que el problema es más sencillo de solucionar con el remove y que en caso de tener muchos elementos los agrupes con un div o con una clase común a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución seria en vez de usar `appendTo()`, usar `html()`. De este modo reemplazarías todo el contenido creado anteriormente. En el ejemplo que te voy a dejar a continuación, "cuerpo" seria el div que va a contener tu menú. Espero que te sea útil, saludos!

**Ejemplo:**

```js
   //CARGA INICIAL DE LA PAGINA.
$(function() {
    if ( window.innerWidth > 500) {
    lalo2()
  } else {
  //SI EL ANCH0 ES MENOR LLAMA A LALO()
    lalo()
  }
});

   
   
   function lalo() {
     $('#cuerpo').html('<ul><li>UNO</li></ul>');
    } //ESTA FUNCION AGREGA UN MENU AL BODY REEMPLAZANDO TODO EL CONTENIDO EXISTENTE.

    function lalo2() {
      $('#cuerpo').html('<ul><li>DOS</li></ul>');
    } //ESTA FUNCION AGREGA UN MENU AL BODY REEMPLAZANDO TODO EL CONTENIDO EXISTENTE.

//CUANDO CAMBIO DE TAMAÑO LA VENTANA PASA ALGO
window.onresize = function (  ) {
  //SI EL ANCHO DE LA VENTANA ES MAYOR A 500 LLAMA A LA FUNCION LALO2()
  if ( window.innerWidth > 500) {
    lalo2()
  } else {
  //SI EL ANCH0 ES MENOR LLAMA A LALO()
    lalo()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cuerpo"></div>
```

Comment: pero en realidad el ejemplo que pongo es bien basico para no "marear" a la persona que acuda en mi ayuda...realmente mi pagina tiene muchas cosas ¿ese html no chancaria toda mi pagina acaso? yo creo que ese html es como el write que machaca todo lo anterior

Comment: machacaría todo lo que tengas en "cuerpo" por eso te decía que cuerpo solo debe contener el menú. No necesariamente debe ser el body.

Comment: pero esta en mi header, y alli hay mas cosas, como el logo y una imagen de fondo :/

Comment: no defería afectar siempre y cuando encapsules el menú en un div. Debes poner el código completo en todo caso, sino no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: ¿pero entonces es definitivo: no se puede eliminar una funcion, asi como con remove que elimina elementos, pero para una funcion?

Comment: Tambien he intentado hacerlo como OBJETO. Es decir, mis dos funciones convertirlas en METODOS, y luego tratar de eliminar el objeto con DELETE, pero no funciona.